# Why create contexts instead of just exporting objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I want to avoid deep nesting of props and I was starting to use React context to do this, but then it occurred to me "why don't I just export objects instead?"

For example, instead of writing:

```
const handleClick: = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  doSomething();
};
const calcPrice = (quantity) = {
  return quantity * 100
};
export const ComponentContext = createContext({});

export const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ComponentContext.Provider value={{ handleClick, calcPrice }}>
      <ChildComponent quantity={12} />
    </ComponentContext.Provider>

}
```

And import it as:

```
export const ChildComponent = (quantity) = {
  const { handleClick, calcPrice } = useContext(ComponentContext);
  const totalPrice = calcPrice(quantity);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Total is ${totalPrice}</button>
}
```

I could instead simply write it as:

```
const handleClick: = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  doSomething();
};
const calcPrice = (quantity) = {
  return quantity * 100
};
export const componentProps = { handleClick, calcPrice };

export const ParentComponent = () => {
  return <ChildComponent quantity={12} />
}
```

And import it as:

```
const { handleSignUpClick, calcPrice } = componentProps;
export const ChildComponent = (quantity) = {
  const totalPrice = calcPrice(quantity);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Total is ${totalPrice}</button>
}
```

What's the advantage of doing it with context instead of with functions?

Comment: What does `doSomething()` in `handleClick` need to do? It seems unlikely for this to not have some sort of dependency on your application state. If `handleClick` doesn't have any dependencies on state or props, then there is no reason to use context.

Comment: It involves changing state (changing the dialogOpen state from false to true so a dialog form opens).

I'm actually using custom react hooks to do this now instead of context or objects as `handleClick()` needs to contain a hook itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your example you're just exporting some helper functions. And in that use case, there might not be any difference between exporting an object (with those functions) and using the `useContext()` hook.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

But, from **React DOCs** (link above), we get that:

> **A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context value changes.** If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can optimize it by using memoization.

How would you achieve that (re-render of the consumers) using an exported object?

From the parent perspective, all that could trigger a re-render of a child component is when you render it with a different `props` object. And how would something that you exported that lives outside of the component function (since you can't export local function variables and 'methods') be able to change the `props` object that is created inside the component function scope?

**TLDR:**

The basic difference is that you can't cause a re-render of consumer children with an exported object. At least not without falling into a complete React anti-pattern.

---

Imagine that you have a `ParentComponent` that render **two expensive child component, that you want to optmize for.** And for that you will use `React.memo()` so you only re-render those child components if their `props` change.

The one that uses context will re-render, because the context property has changed, but **the one that uses the exported variable will not re-render because all that has changed lives outside of React.**

**SandBox example:**
https://vq30v.codesandbox.io/

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SomeContext from "./SomeContext";
import ExpensiveChildComponent from "./ExpensiveChildComponent";
import ExpensiveChildComponentExport from "./ExpensiveChildComponentExport";

let count = null; // VARIABLE THAT WILL BE EXPORTED
console.log("Outside ParentComponent...");

function ParentComponent() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  console.log("Rendering Parent Component...");
  count = myState; // UPDATING THE EXPORTED VARIABLE

  function handleClick() {
    setMyState(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }

  // SETTING UP CONTEXT PROVIDER
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeContext.Provider value={myState}>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Count</button>
        <h3>Uses Context</h3>
        <ExpensiveChildComponent />
        <h3>Uses Exported Object</h3>
        <ExpensiveChildComponentExport />
      </SomeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

console.log("After ParentComponent declaration...");

export { ParentComponent, count }; // EXPORTING COMPONENT AND VARIABLE
```

**ExpensiveChildComponent.js** (uses context)

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import SomeContext from "./SomeContext";

// REACT MEMO WILL ONLY UPDATE IF PROPS OR CONTEXT HAS CHANGED
const ExpensiveChildComponent = React.memo(function ExpensiveChildComponent() {
  console.log("Rendering ExpensiveChildComponent...");
  const context = useContext(SomeContext);
  return <div>{context}</div>;
});

export default ExpensiveChildComponent;
```

**ExpensiveChildComponentExport.js** (uses an exported property)

```
import React from "react";
import { count } from "./ParentComponent"; // IMPORTING THE EXPORTED VARIABLE

console.log("Outside ExpensiveChildComponentExport...");

// REACT MEMO WILL ONLY UPDATE IF PROPS OR CONTEXT HAS CHANGED (AND BOTH ARE NOT BEING USED)
const ExpensiveChildComponentExport = React.memo(
  function ChildComponentExport() {
    console.log("Rendering ExpensiveChildComponentExport...");
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>{count}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
);

export default ExpensiveChildComponentExport;
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**NOTE:**

If you remove `React.memo` from the `ExpensiveChildComponentExport` it will re-render, because React creates a new `props` object on each render (it will be an empty object, but it will be a different one on every time). That's why I added `React.memo()`, because it will perform a shallow compare on the `props` object. So I can illustrate the behavior that `useContext` has and an mere exported object doesn't.

Comment: Yes you can re render component even when using exported object. You can employ several techniques. One might be observable mutation libraries such as MobX. Otherwise you can employ your own obervables (like RxJs) or even based subscription and re-render the component either by updating components stare or forcing manual re render.